# Selenium can not proceed as chrome Does not loads UI

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

Sometimes, Selenium C# launches chrome as well as the website, but is unable to interact with it.

On close inspection, I noticed that it was because chrome was not in focus and was not loading the UI.

As soon as I focused the chrome, I would see a white screen for half a second, and then UI appeared. And as soon as UI appeared, the test started running well.

I feel like chrome can not get enough system resources without the background. Any help would be appreciated. I never faced the issue in selenium-python.

Website is - web.whatsapp.com

Comment: what it is supposed to do? what it is doing?

Answer (score 0):

It look like you are not giving enough time for page to load. You can use any of the below wait technique.

**Explicit Wait in Selenium C#**

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
String ele_xpath = "<xpath of element>"
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
IWebElement welcomeMessage = 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.XPath(ele_xpath)));
// Here I have assumed first page is having a welcome message, you can use any element present on your page. Your script will wait up to 30 sec for element to appear before it will throw timeoutexception
```

**implicit wait in Selenium C#**

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
//Above will make script to wait for each element up to 30 sec
```

**waiting in C#:**

You can ask your script to wait for a defined millisecond before executing next line of code:

```
Thread.Sleep(6000);
# It will for 6 sec
```

**Fluent Wait in Selenium C#**

```
Wait<WebDriver> fluentWait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
       .withTimeout(30, SECONDS) // this defines the total amount of time to wait for
       .pollingEvery(2, SECONDS) // this defines the polling frequency
       .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class); // this defines the exception to ignore 
      WebElement welcomeMessage= fluentWait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
     public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver)  //in this method defined your own subjected conditions for which we need to wait for
     {  return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Welcome')]"));
}});
```

**Note :** You can use any of the above wait method. However each of them have their own advantage/ disadvantage. Please read more about them and difference at below link:
https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/selenium-waits-implicit-explicit-fluent-and-sleep/

Comment: Sorry but at least you should have asked in comments. I am already using explicit wait.

Comment: Dint say sorry mate. Its all right, as you did not mentioned in your question, i put some information here. Also i am not sure if you have tried headless browser if UI load is an issue. Cheers :)

Comment: Headless is an issue too.  I can not run headless chrome nor chromium since a month. I wonder why its not a widespread issue. At least chrome-dev should make issues more open and allow us to open issues on github.

Comment: I can not agree more with you. Any way I will try with python script and let you know if i am able to replicate and solve the issue.Thanks for highlighting!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following - it will force focus on Chrome (from the information provided I can assume there a JS event which blocks the page loading or trigger onfocus event).

```
var driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize(); // will focus or at least bring to front

// other things to try - switch
driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
driver.SwitchTo().ActiveElement();

// other things to try - JavaScript
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("document.querySelector('body').focus();")
```